# MVC 3 HtmlHelper does not contain an extension for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, razor

I'm getting HtmlHelper does not contain an extension for LabelFor, DropDownListFor, etc.

The razor views compile, but no designer support.

The problem is detailed by Rick Strahl here:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/14/Odd-MVC-4-Beta-Razor-Designer-Issue

I'm using MVC 3 on VS 2010 on .NET 4, xp sp3

I've tried:

- web.config appsetting for webpages version
- web.config compilation targetframework=4
- using vs 2010 commandline to remove web.pages 3.5 dll
- re-installing vs 2010
- using vs 11 beta, same problem
- using vs 2010 on win 7

Comment: I also tried adding the <system.web.webPages.razor> section

Comment: you need to add ref in the NON-ROOT (that is Views\Web.config ) web.config file. Install VS 11 RC over your beta, build a new project and compare the Views\Web.config files. Looks like you are new to MVC, so your best off using Visual Studio 2012 RC and MVC 4 RC (with .Net 4.5 RC)